# multicolumn combobox just like a combobox in winforms

Tags: c#, user-controls

i have developed a user control for winforms in C#.Net framework 3.5, it is multi-column combo, named 'DataCombo'.

i have created it with the help of Textbox and DataGridView, it looks like a combobox, and also behave as it, cursor jump on textbox list will appeared, the only difference is, that combobox provides only one column, and in this 'datacombo' we can show more than one column, 
and we can provide facility like sorting (just like a explorer), filter, column re-ordering etc.

this is very useful component to me.

my problem is that, when i put this control to a frame or groupbox or any container control, and my list size is more than container's size, than list will cut off as container size,
i want this component should behave like a combobox when we put a combobox and its list size goes to out of container, although the list appears correctly

any suggestion how could it do this 
[image: in this image first red circle inidcating combobox Beauvoir and in second circle in my 'datacombo' its list is cutted off]

i want some like this 
[image: i want solution some like this]

Answer (score 0):

Turn `off` the visibility of `dataGridView` in `UserControl` and set following properties of `UserControl` in design mode.

1. `AutoSize=True`
2. `AutoSizeMode-GrowAndShrink`

Comment: sir, i don't want to re-size my control as per it's container's size, elsewhere i want to show list out of it's container;s area.

Comment: @HaiderAli You cannot draw anything outside the Usercontrol.

Comment: not the usercontrol, but i want to draw user control out side of its container control.